# Transfer statusbar values from one form to another

Tags: delphi

I have two identical statusbars (AdvOfficeStatusBar)  on each form. That means Form1 has the same status bar as the Form2.Now,before I close the Form1 I would like all the values from the status bar to be transfered to that one on the form2. I suppose I could do it one by one like... :

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text;
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text;
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[2].Text := Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[2].Text;
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[4].Text := Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[4].Text;
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[5].Text := Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[5].Text;
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[6].Text := Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[6].Text;  
end;
```

I was wondering if there's a more simple way?Less code...

Comment: `.. .Panels.Assign(..)`, if an AdvOfficeStatusBar is anything like the VCL status bar. Otherwise use a for loop, it's less lines if you have more than three panels (including index counter var declaration).

Comment: Well, looping seems quite obvious. One wonders why you are using a status bar as the primary storage for important state. Wouldn't it be better to hold the state in a non-visual store and then be able to transfer it to a visual control for display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're suffering from an [anti-pattern called `copy-paste-programming`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming)

It makes for very easy programming, but difficult maintenance.
Every time you add a line to one statusbar, you have to go back and update to code to have it be linked into the other statusbar.
It's easy to forget updating the code and ehm well it's work, which is why this is bad practice.

A better way is to use `Assign` or if that does not work a loop. Both are demonstrated below.

Note that the `Panel` is an `array property`.
Normally every array_property has a associated `count` property.
I'm not sure what it is in this instance, but I'm guessing it's called `PanelCount`.

As per David's suggestion it's better to store the state somewhere inside your program, because you might redesign the form and lose the StatusBar, in which case you'd also lose the storage.

```
type 
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    StatusStore: array of string;
    .....
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Initialisation, you cannot use a loop, unless you'd read it from a file.
  SetLength(StatusStore,6);
  StatusStore[0]:= 'a';
  StatusStore[1]:= 'b';
  StatusStore[2]:= 'c';
  StatusStore[3]:= 'd';
  StatusStore[4]:= 'e';
  StatusStore[5]:= 'f';
end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,maxi: integer;
begin
  StatusStore[0]:= 'Showing Form2';
  Maxi:= SizeOf(StatusStore); 
  i:= 0;
  AdvOfficeStatusBar1.PanelCount:= Maxi;
  while (i < Maxi) do begin
    AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[i].Text:= StatusStore[i]; 
  end; {while}
  Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels.Assign(Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels);
end;
```

Now whatever data is to be displayed and however many items there are, the display will update.
You can even program the loop to skip an item if you want the first or last item to be different for each form.

Comment: its just values obtained on startup of the programe (from logon screen) like computer name,ip,username....I want them on the second form too (if login successful) since its the main form. no big deal...

Comment: cant compile your suggestion...no such thing as panelcount:[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(48): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'PanelCount' . Changing to AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels.Count:= Maxi; gives me :[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(48): E2129 Cannot assign to a read-only property.

Comment: why not just : Form1.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels.Assign(Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels); It works ....

Comment: @user763539, I was trying to give you options, rather than just a copy-pastable answer with no meat in it.